# Error in open.connection Timeout was reached

Tags: r

I have this currently working. Im new to R so idk how connections work and its one thing google didnt help.

My code gets me numbers from a crest api.

```
df <- readWorksheetFromFile("marketTypeIDS.xls", sheet=1, startRow = 1, endCol = 2)

typeIDs <- unname(unlist(df[,1]))

calcday<-as.numeric(Sys.Date())-30
currentdate<-as.numeric(Sys.Date())

itemcount <- 0
monthvolumes <- seq(1:11897)

baseurl <- "https://public-crest.eveonline.com/market/10000048/types/"

monthlyvolume <- (0)

tmpvol <- (0)

for (i in 1:11897) 
    {
    itemcount <- fromJSON(paste0(baseurl, typeIDs[i], "/history/"), flatten = TRUE)$totalCount
    Sys.sleep(0.034)
    if (itemcount ==0)
    {
    monthvolumes[i] <- 0
    }
    else 
        {
        repeat
            {
            currentdate <- as.Date(fromJSON(paste0(baseurl, typeIDs[i], "/history/"), flatten = TRUE)$items[itemcount,8])
            Sys.sleep(0.034)                    
            if (as.numeric(currentdate)<calcday)
                {
                break
                }
            tmpvol <- fromJSON(paste0(baseurl, typeIDs[i], "/history/"), flatten = TRUE)$items[itemcount,6]
            Sys.sleep(0.034)
            monthlyvolume <- monthlyvolume+tmpvol
            itemcount <- itemcount-1
            if (itemcount==0)
                {
                break
                }
            }               
        monthvolumes[i]<-monthlyvolume
        monthlyvolume<-0
        }                                           
    }
```

It stops at ~700 (should do it over 11000 times tho) and then gives me this error:

```
 Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : Timeout was reached 
6 open.connection(con, "rb") 
5 open(con, "rb") 
4 parse_con(txt, 1024^2, bigint_as_char) 
3 parseJSON(txt, bigint_as_char) 
2 fromJSON_string(txt = txt, simplifyVector = simplifyVector, simplifyDataFrame = simplifyDataFrame, 
    simplifyMatrix = simplifyMatrix, flatten = flatten, ...) 
1 fromJSON(paste0(baseurl, typeIDs[i], "/history/"), flatten = TRUE) 
In addition: Warning message:
closing unused connection 3 (https://public-crest.eveonline.com/market/10000048/types/18/history/)
```

This connection was created on the first run of the for loop (it starts with the 18 in the link)
How could I close this connection beforehand so it doesnt break the loop? (this just ran about an hour so its hard to test through "trying")

Thanks for help in advance!
If u have any other suggestions my ears are open!

Comment: since you're actually getting an error, you can use `try` or `tryCatch` around your `fromJSON` calls (I'd make a wrapper function for `fromJSON`), catch the error, do something clever with it and then the script will run. Alternatively, you can use `httr::GET/POST`, set the timeout value there (just in case this is a legit delay on the server side) and then also use `try/tryCatch` as a wrapper. We don't have `marketTypeIDS.xls` to help test with, so that's prbly the best you're going to get.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xl8t343iwfv3sr5/eveQT.rar?dl=0                    here the full source code, and the xls document.                        your asnwer makes good sense. allthough i still would like to know how to close this connection and id like to know why everything breaks when theres a timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this so that it doesnt matter at what point it breaks.
It always starts at the last written record if there is one.

So instead of looping over 11897 records from 1 I did read out the last written thing from the output file.

Ive wrapped all of it in a Try/Catch like @hrbrmstr suggested and I have put all that in an endless loop 
 that only breaks when the last record was written.

Not a beautiful solution but one that perfectly worked and was easy to implement, since it only restarted a few times and ran till the end, and I only needed it a few times.